# Lists to Dict need return method

Tags: python

I am trying to return a dictionary with key/value pairs, but this is what I got and it does not work.

```
def lists_to_dict(keys, value):
    for i in values:
        value[i]=map(int, value[i])
        return keys
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is unclear. What is your input to the function, what is the current output, and what is the expected output? Please [edit] this to make a [mcve]

Comment: Are you just trying to do `dict(zip(keys, values))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (best option):

```
return dict(zip(keys, value))
```

or this (a bit overly verbose):

```
return {key: v for key, v in zip(keys, value)}
```

or this (to show that one just arrived to Python from C++):

```
return {keys[i]: value[i] for i in range(len(keys))}
```

For `{key: ...}` construction you can google [dict comprehensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20dict%20comprehension).

For `zip` you can google [zip](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20zip%20two%20lists).

These are important things so they might be worth reading, hence the links.

Comment: To be clear, #3 is extremely non-idiomatic (and slower, and more prone to errors with mismatched input sizes). Basically any case of `for i in range(len(someseq)):` which does `someseq[i]` is a problem; indexing another sequence with it makes it worse. #2 is more customizable, but not necessary unless you're filtering or mutating the keys or values.

Comment: Yes, added this characteristic to the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert a two list into a dict, try using the zip command.

**my version**

```
def list_to_dict(keys, value):
return dict(zip(keys, value))

list_to_dict(['A', 'B', 'C'], [10, 20, 30])
```

**Result**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a for loop for "value**S**", yet you give the function "value"
First you should initialise the dictionary, try:

```
def lists_to_dict(keys, values): 
    out_dictionary = {}
    for idx, key in enumerate(keys):  ## idx will be an integer as index of keys
        out_dictionary[key] = values[idx] ## assumes values and keys is equal length
    return out_dictionary
```